# How do I update Windows 10 IoT Core without re-flashing SD card?

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

After setting up Windows 10 IoT Core on Raspberry Pi 2 and getting all comfortable with it, along comes Visual Studio 2015 with the message: "Please upgrade your remote debugger to match Visual Studio." which apparently means repeating the entire installation (flash from scratch) as described here http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SetupRPI.htm

Is a "reinstall from scratch" the only way to currently update the Windows 10 IoT Core ? What about something like apt-get update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the release of Windows 10 IoT Core build 10586, you can update Windows IoT over the Internet just like we do in Windows.

To update Windows IoT, follow the steps:

1. Connect your Raspberry Pi 2's Ethernet to the Internet (i.e. with Internet Router or Modem).
2. Connect your computer/tablet to the same network on which Raspberry Pi 2 is connected.
3. Open Windows IoT's Web-management portal.
4. Login to the Web-management portal.
5. From the left black-panel 'UTILITIES', click 'Windows Update'.
6. Finally, to update Windows 10 IoT Core, click on 'Check for updates' button and wait for the magic.

> **Newer to web management portal?**
>   Please refer "Web-Management Portal" section of this ProTip article: https://www.hackster.io/AnuragVasanwala/windows-10-iot-core-setting-startup-app-887ed0

Comment: Ok, having solved that one (I wonder if Microsoft had told us this in advance somewhere?) now working on an over-the-air update solution for deployed aps. In case there is something in the works there, please save us some time by letting us know. Thanks!

Comment: Will the update service mentioned also have a feature or api to let us update our deployed apps somehow, or is it for Microsoft internal use only?

Comment: At this moment, this update service is available to Update Windows IoT only. And even we can't disable it. (You can disable such auto update function but you need Windows 10 IoT Core Enterprise.)

Comment: To update our deployed apps, we need to redeploy them with newer one or we can supply AppX file (which can be generated by Visual Studio) to deploy apps without Visual Studio using Windows IoT's Web-Management (http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/tools/DevicePortal.htm).

Comment: Most of DevicePortal functionality are available in the PowerShell (even more than the DevicePortal). Right now, I have no idea about availability of such feature to access DevicePortal via secured remote login. I'll update if I found something regarding that.

Comment: Revisiting this: it appears that a lot has changed. To get industry-grade update capabilities, do we need to move to the oem-editions and is there a free one that can achieve updates?